# How do I seek beyond end of existing file?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, file-io

how do I seek beyond end of existing file ?

Consider I have `test.bin` which is 1000 bytes.

Then I run following

```
std::filebuf fbuf;
fbuf.open("c:\\test.bin", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::binary);
fbuf.pubseekoff(10, std::ios_base::end);
fbuf.sputc(1);
fbuf.close();
```

After running this example I expect new filesize to be 1011 bytes. But instead it adds 0x01 at the end of existing file making it 1001 bytes.

Interestingly though it works the way I want it when it's new file.

I'm running this on Windows 7 x64 but target platform will be Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `std::ios_base::app` flag. This causes all writes to occur at the end of the file. If you want writes to be performed at the current position, you cannot specify this flag when you open the file.

> `ios_base::app` Append file; that is, always write to the end of the file

Comment: In other words it's impossible to quickly pre-allocate additional space in existing file ?

Comment: It's trivial. Just write way past the end of the file. Your code, however, doesn't do that. It writes *at* the end of the file.

Comment: Нузю That's what I'm trying to do. I expected `pubseekoff` to move position past the end of file. What do I need to change in my code ?

Comment: You need to write at the position you seeked to, not at the end of the file. (Did you actually read my answer?)